# Adding cache control directive to HTTP response header

Tags: http-headers

I am trying to add **Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store** to HTTP response header. I put the following to Web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It yields **Pragma: no-cache** directive in the header.

```
CONNECT ...:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: ...
Pragma: no-cache
```

Is this equivalent to **Cache-Control: no-cache**? How do change Web.Config to produce **Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store** in the HTTP header on IIS 8.5? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Cache-Control` header is for HTTP 1.1, not HTTP 1.0, and your `CONNECT` request indicates that it is an HTTP 1.0 client.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Two more questions: 1) How do I add Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store for HTTP 1.1? 2) How to upgrade the web server (IIS) to HTTP 1.1? Thanks!

Comment: From the [IIS `<clientCache>` docs](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache), you might try using the `cacheControlCustom` attribute, _i.e._: `<clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" cacheControlCustom="no-cache, no-store" />`.  You may find that you need `cacheControlCustom`, *or* `cacheControlMode`, but not both.  As for upgrading the client to use HTTP 1.1, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Castaglia. I found in <a href="http://serverfault.com/questions/457040/why-is-iis-7-5-seeing-some-requests-as-http-1-0">this post</a>, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store appears in the HTTP 1.0 response header. I agree that was introduced in HTTP 1.1. But why it was in the HTTP 1.0 header?

Comment: Some servers send *both* `Pragma` *and* `Cache-Control` response headers, regardless of HTTP version; some do not.